# Using iText to convert/burn "Stamp" annotations into images

Tags: java, pdf, annotations, itext, stamp

I have a PDF file contains various types of annotations, one of them is of type "Stamp".
I'm using [iText](http://itextpdf.com/itext.php), and I need to convert this stamp into image on the same position with the same size, then remove this stamp.

How can I achieve this?
Is there any way to read `PdfName.STAMP` as an image?

Thanks,

Comment: You'll have to clarify what you mean by image. Do you want to "flatten" the annotation, meaning you want it to be part of the content stream as vector data? Or do you really want to convert it to a raster image (which would probably result in one pretty ugly stamp).

Comment: @bruno-lowagie Actually I want it to be flattened, so stamp not to be edited by users. But also I'm interested to know how to export them as raster images.

Comment: Export to raster images: I can't help you with that. Flatten: as soon as I find the time (very difficult for me as I have a lot of work), I could try making you an example.

Comment: OK, I've taken a brief look at the problem, but the solution I'm thinking about will only work if an appearance was created for your stamp annotations. So the question is: do you have a PDF you can share. If not: you're not going to get any help.